# Use @@servername and db_name() on notify operator task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, maintenance-plans

I'm setting up a maintenance plan and on error I added a "Notify operator task" with some text. But I want to be able to add something like:

> Backup failed on MyDatabase\Instance_name...blablabla

I guess I should use @@SERVERNAME and DB_NAME(db.database_id) someway but so far can't find how to do it, maybe is trivial but no luck find in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notify Operator Tasks are independent of a database context.

Furthermore, the text that's entered into the Properties dialog box gets passed into a statement resembling the following (obtained by clicking the `View T-SQL` button):

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_notify_operator @name=N'My Operator',
    @subject=N'Subject',@body=N'Message Body'
```

So what do you do?

Getting the server context is easily solved by switching to an Execute T-SQL Statement Task where you can put whatever SQL you want in there.

That doesn't solve the database name issue, though, because you'll get back either `master` or `msdb` and not any particular user database. I don't believe it's possible using Maintenance Plans to get the database name for what you're trying to do. The Back Up Database Task is entirely self-contained.

What you would need to do is use SSIS proper and put a Back Up Database Task and Notify Operator Task within a loop container, where the flow would be executed for each database individually.

Or, you could take a completely different approach and use a script-based backup solution and customize it to suit your exact needs.

Comment: Thanks Jon, nice answer. And what you would suggest as "different approach"? Maybe using Ola Hallengren maintenance scripts? Does it allows to have this kind of tweaks?

Comment: @Yaroslav: Yes, exactly. There are a bunch of good ones out there, all free and open source. They're just stored procedures, so you can modify them any way you want.

Comment: Ok, will check it out as soon as possible, thanks again.

Comment: @Yaroslav: You're welcome.

Comment: For the server name portion, I recommend changing the DISPLAY NAME in the mail account configuration to include the instance name. For example, all the e-mails from my servers show "[InstanceName] SQL Server Alert" in the FROM column in my mail client. That way there is no confusion regarding what server sent the alert.

Comment: @SomeGuy: Yes, that's a very good point.